# SQLcl connect to APEX workspace

Tags: connection, apex, workspace, sqlcl

The Oracle APEX workspace is on a remote vm, which I connect to via vpn. I have only the developer role for the workspace, not a database user. Also there is no cloud account.

I am trying to follow the steps described in this article: https://diveintoapex.com/2022/06/12/using-scriptable-devops-to-save-time/, but it fails at the first step, to connect to the workspace: sql appuser/password@host:port/servicename.

My question is: In my case, is it even possible from my computer, through SQLcl, to connect to the workspace and export the workspace?

In my connection string, I have tried using my workspace username and password, with the vm's ip address as host, the workspace port number (7001) as port, "apx21" as servicename. But it fails:

```
SQL> conn xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx/password@10.xx.x.xx:7001/apx21
The connect request was not recognized: please type HELP CONNECT to find out more about the supported combinations of command options
```

I also tried using my first name and last name without the period in between, as username. It fails too:

```
SQL> conn xxxxxxxxxx/password@10.xx.x.xx:7001/apx21
  USER          = xxxxxxxxxx
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xx.x.xx:7001/apx21
  Error Message = IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 32399 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
```

Comment: You can only make a database connection using database user accounts, not with APEX workspace users. However, each APEX workspace will be associated with an Oracle Schema (which is the USER) - you would connect with that.